# javascript pointers array or #define for abbreviation

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers, defined

I have a multi-dimensional array with different types of variables, like this:

```
array = [  [[file, name, visible], [ArrayPoint, ArrayOther], ...],  [[file2,...], ..]  ]
```

now in my code multiple times I have to call (for example) an Array() of points which is located in myArray [X] [1] [0].

I wanted to know if there was the possibility of creating definitions or pointers to the array position to shorten the code, because often I do not remember the variable positions.

```
// access the value at the address available in pointer
var *pointArray = &myArray[X][1][0];

// my code
*pointArray.push(pint_x, point_y);

============== VS ==============

myArray[X][1][0].push(pint_x, point_y);
```

thank you very much!! and good evening.

by Marco.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have pointers/reference types, but you can do what you need with just a normal variable, since JavaScript uses pass-by-sharing.

Comment: See [Call by (Object) Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing): "However, *since the function has access to the same object as the caller (no copy is made) .. mutations to those objects are visible to the caller because the object is not copied or cloned* — it is shared." The same rule holds for any variable assignment in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
var pointArray = myArray[X][1][0];
```

It will make a copy of the reference to the array at `myArray[X][1][0]`. Therefore, any subsequent mutations to the elements of `pointArray` will also change the elements of `myArray[X][1][0]`.

Note that reassigning a new value to `pointArray` as a whole would not effect `myArray[X][1][0]`, since that would only make `pointArray` store something else.

Assignments do not copy/clone objects in JavaScript, they only make the variable on the left-hand side reference the same object as what's on the right-hand side.

```js
var outer = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]];
var inner = outer[1];

inner.push(6);
console.log(JSON.stringify(outer));

inner = [];
console.log(JSON.stringify(outer));
```

Comment: I prefer simply saying "assignments do *not* copy/clone objects in JavaScript". This behavior can then be explained with [call by (object) sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

Comment: @user2864740 But that isn't descriptive of what they ***do*** do. I'd rather describe what they are rather than describe what they aren't.

Comment: Once that rule is established it's easy to follow through: an object is itself, and changes to that object anywhere affect it everywhere.

Comment: @user2864740 The wording is tricky on this. It's tempting to say that all object types are reference types, but that would be misleading for what a reassignment does.

Comment: All objects in JavaScript have use by sharing semantics and act as "reference types" in other languages. Not all values (ie. the primitive values) are objects, but values that are not objects are also immutable (and thus irrelevant to call by sharing which describes the behavior of mutable objects).

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks I understand.
my problem was that I created the variable called before filling the main array.

this is because I create the empty array structure, but is filled successively by the program events.

now to solve the problem I create the connection variable after the first event push to the primary array.

thank you very much for your availability.